# Regex Match Collection Identifying partial match .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, wildcard

I have a string pattern intended to match to user utterances. I am struggling with match collection feature of regex.

```
string pat = ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bbought\b)(?=.*\bid\b).*$
string user = "I would like to see id of bought goods.";
```

Correct matching utterance from user would be .i.e.
***I would like to see id of bought goods.***

Problem:

Is there any possibility to use match collection feature in regex to determine if a user has only entered a part of required utterance i.e. 
I would like to see **id** of **goods**. (but missing ***bought***)

I am required to detect the missing part of the pattern/match.

So that the user can be prompted and informed that he/she has missed ***bought*** in utterance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check each word separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, but... `IndexOf`**

Yes, using a match collection or even a capture collection is *technically possible* here (but see the discussion below). For instance,

```
\b(?:(I|would|like|to|see|id|of|bought|goods)\b\s*)+
```

Will match the whole sentence in one pass, and the Capture Collection for Group 1 will include all the words that were present.

Alternately, you could use

```
\b(?:I|would|like|to|see|id|of|bought|goods)\b
```

to place all the matches in a match collection.

But then you'd have to inspect the match collection or the capture collection to see which word might be missing. With all that work, you'd be better off looking for each word separately (as @Jerry suggested) using `IndexOf`

Comment: Hi zx81, Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried your method but only collection match (id , bought). Its ignoring to match goods from ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b) block. Can you suggest on how to make the solution to match multiple words mentioned in this block? I can't make separate block for each word because I have too many of them. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not understanding what you are asking now. (Both solutions I mentioned work.) Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry. When I am matching string pat = ^(?=.*\b(?:goods?|things?|items?)\b)(?=.*\bbought\b)(?=.*\bid\b).*$ with the solution above the match collection only yeilds match for ( id , bought) but ignores "goods" from the third block. Thanks